# Web API Help Pages not loading documentation XML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I'm trying to set up the [ASP.NET Help Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) to run in an existing MVC project, though pointing towards the documentation file from a Web API project in the same solution. Convention has the Help Pages running inside the Web API that it's documenting but in this case I want it in a sibling MVC project.

The Web API project outputs its documentation XML file in a folder within the MVC project.

I've installed the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/) in the MVC project. This creates a class `\Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs`, and within this class's `Register` method I've passed the `XmlDocumentationProvider` the path to the Web API's documentation file.

But when I load the page, it's empty, aside from a title and a placeholder description.

Upon debugging the `HelpController.Index` method, I can see in the returned `IApiExplorer` that the `_apiDescriptions` are empty.

[image: Screenshot from Help Pages running inside MVC project]

However, if I install the Help Pages directly into the Web API project and debug the same method, I can see that the `_apiDescriptions` are now present.

[image: Screenshot from Help Pages running inside Web API project]

Can anyone explain what the Web API project is doing or has configured which the MVC project isn't doing or hasn't configured?

Answer (score 8):

Just set this up myself, and I think I ran into a similar issue, if i'm reading what you're saying correctly.

Try the following:

1. Go to Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs. Around line 36, you'll want to make sure you uncommented the line as below:

```html
//// Uncomment the following to use the documentation from XML documentation file.
            config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ApiDocumentation.xml")));
```

And make sure the path is correct. I happened to put my xml file in the App_Data directory.

2. Go to Project=>Properties=>Build. Under Output, make sure the "XML documentation file" box is checked, and point it to App_Data\ApiDocumentation.XML (assuming you put it in the same place i did above.
3. If i remember correctly, i had to make sure i added the .xml file to the project- i had some problems when i tried publishing it to our test server at work and it said the file couldn't be found. After you build, simply go to App_Data, right click on the folder, and add existing item. navigate to App_Data in your file system and select the xml file.

This will hopefully fix your problem!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone else that stumbles across this, I had started with a blank template from VS and added the help files via the Nuget package.

Because it was a blank template and I had no areas set up, it was missing the following from the global.asax

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

This prevented the HelpPageConfig.Register from being called and thus, the Xml Documentation provider was never set.